# Waggle dance behavior when `Arrowheads` is used to label an arrow

Tags: graphics

This has got to be the weirdest *Mathematica* bug in my (not all that small) collection...

I'm using **"10.4.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (February 26, 2016)"**.

Here's the code:

```
annotatedArrow[p_, q_, label_] := {
     Arrowheads[{{-0.05, 0},
                 {$MachineEpsilon, 0.5,
                  Graphics[Inset[Framed[Style[label, Medium],
                                        Background -> LightGray,
                                        FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0], Opacity[0]]]]]},
                 { 0.05, 1}}],
      Arrow[{p, q}]
   }

Manipulate[
  Graphics[{annotatedArrow[{0, height}, {right, height}, "wannadance?"]},
           PlotRange -> {{0, 0.2}, {0, 0.25}}, ImageSize -> 200] // Framed,
  {{height, 0.2  }, 0, 0.24, LabeledSlider}, {{right , 0.136}, 0, 0.2 , LabeledSlider}
]
```

The `annotatedArrow` function is adapted from a similarly named function given in the documentation for `Arrow`.

This code produces a `Manipulate` widget, with two sliders on it, plus a `Graphic` featuring a labeled double-headed arrow.  (See figures below.)

The "height" slider controls the vertical position of the arrow.

The "right" slider controls the position of the right arrowhead.

These behaviors are available "by design".

But, as a ***bonus***, depending on the setting of these sliders, the label on the arrow will be tilted in one of three possible orientations:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I have no idea why this happens, since the code I'm using does not mention rotations at all.

Comment: Possibly it's due to some internal manipulation of `Arrowheads`. Try to change that `$MachineEpsilon` to 0 and you can find it's position is shifting! So I strongly suspect when dealing with arrowheads' drawing, mma do some not-that-accurate evaluations which leads to some numerical error, and by some mechanisms determining `Arrowhead`'s direction like `ArcTan[ $MachineEpsilon,error introduced]`, the direction shifts. A simple solution shall be using `1.*^-10` instead of `$MachineEpsilon` ------ They are so risky and so easily interfered by internal not-that-precise evaluations.

Comment: @Wjx: Your idea with using `1.*^-10` instead of `$MachineEpsilon` was an inspired one.  Thanks!

Comment: Using `$MachineEpsilon` caught my eye as suspicious as well. This value is sometimes used as "a small number", but in relative terms it is huge compared to zero and negligible compared to numbers larger than unity. So while I agree with @Wjx that this is probably an effect of imprecise numerical evaluation, in choosing such a value that by its nature has equal magnitude to the discontinuity of the floating-point number line, you are almost asking for such effects to be emphasized.

Comment: I know that this clearly looks like a bug, but it would still be good if in the future you could stick to protocol and not use the [tag:bugs] tag on your own posts.  Let someone else add it.  If high rep users keep doing this, how can we tell newcomers not to do it?

Comment: If I set the size to `$MachineEpsilon/10^29`, then often the "wannadance?" disappears (except sometimes for the top row of pixels) until I click somewhere or scroll.

Comment: @Szabolcs: will do.  (Actually, if it were up to me, now I'd delete the post altogether, but it already has answers.)

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I would not delete the question. I am just asking you to show a good example.  Do not add the tag to *your own* question. Do add the other to *other people's* questions when you are confident that there is a bug, that others would agree with you and that there would be no controversy. When you add the tag, also [add the standard bug header](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1610/12). This is a great help with daily site maintenance.

Comment: @Szabolcs: My desire to delete the question is independent of your comment.  But thanks for the advice.  I will follow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if this is the programmer breaking an unwritten rule about the numerics of graphics. I mean I would expect numerics issues in graphics, just like in other floating-point computing. For example, `Cos[Pi/2.] != 0` returns `True`.

Some evidence for [@Wjx's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141039/waggle-dance-bug#comment381043_141039) and the preceding cosine example:

```
Graphics[{
  Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}],
  Text[
   Framed[Style["wanndance?", Medium], Background -> LightGray, 
     FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0], Opacity[0]]],
   {0, 0},
   {0, 0},
   Through[{Cos, Sin}[ArcTan[$MachineEpsilon, Cos[Pi/2.]]]]  (* direction vector *)
  }], 
 ImageSize -> Tiny]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Looks like the same angle:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'm not sure it is fair to call this a bug in *Mathematica*.

Comment: The behavior of `Arrowheads[{{x, ...}, ...}]` is discontinuous at `x = 0`.  (This motivated my in-retrospect-unwise fix with `$MachineEpsilon`).  That discontinuity of behavior is a design bug, IMO.  I see no justification for it, even if `x = 0` is a corner case.

Comment: I see. That's a somewhat different issue. According to the docs, the scaling factor `x` is the ratio between a unit in one coordinate system and the width of the graphic. Thus it is supposed to be greater than zero by definition.  Unless you set your unit to be zero. Could be done, but it won't have standard properties. E.g. a line from `{a, b}` to `{c, d}` becomes a line from `{0, 0}` to `{0, 0}` if you scale by zero. That's ok for drawing the scaled line, but no good if you need its direction. One might like to ship out the scaled coordinates and be done, but it won't work on your example.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to specify `$MachineEpsilon` in the definition of `annotatedArrow`. I believe a correct specification would be would `Automatic`. The following code which uses `Automatic` is entirely well-behaved.

```
annotatedArrow[p_, q_, label_] :=
  {Arrowheads[
     {{-0.05, 0},
      {Automatic, 0.5, 
         Graphics[
           Inset[Framed[Style[label, Medium], 
           Background -> LightGray, 
           FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0], Opacity[0]]]]]},
      {0.05, 1}}],
   Arrow[{p, q}]}
```

I assert the bug demonstrated in the question is not a Mathematica bug, but a programming error on the part of the OP.